# Can I track memory issues by job id in GCP Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a scheduler that calls GCP functions when a job needs to be processed.  I pass the job id to Google Functions and want to be able to track which functions (by the job id) are using the most memory, number of executions, etc.

For example, when the memory exceeds a limit, I would like to be able to tell which job it was that called the function that exceeded the limit.

Is that possible with custom metrics in Google Cloud Monitoring?

I'm following this example but I'm not sure what to fill out for the commented values:

```
async function writeTimeSeriesData() {
    const projectId = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID";
    const dataPoint = {
        interval: {
            endTime: {
                seconds: Date.now() / 1000
            }
        },
        value: {
            doubleValue: 123.45 // I think this should be the job_id
        }
    };

    const timeSeriesData = {
        metric: {
            type: "custom.googleapis.com/stores/daily_sales", // I'm not sure what to use here, maybe "custom.googleapis.com/jobs/id"
            labels: {
                store_id: "Pittsburgh" // I could maybe add the job name here?
            }
        },
        resource: {
            type: "global",
            labels: {
                project_id: projectId
            }
        },
        points: [dataPoint]
    };

    const request = {
        name: client.projectPath(projectId),
        timeSeries: [timeSeriesData]
    };

    // Writes time series data
    const result = await client.createTimeSeries(request);
    console.log("Done writing time series data.", result);
}
```

#### Update

Here is another explanation of the same issue I'm trying to solve (maybe this version is clearer) :)

I'm using Google Cloud Monitoring and would like to add a custom metric to help solve this issue.  I have thousands of "jobs", each job will call the same GC Function but with specific user parameters.  Sometimes a job has an error or the memory exceeds what I would expect.  In that case, I would like to be able to identify which parameters were passed to GC Function so I can re-run the job and debug the issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to get the details of memory usage and list the Job ID via Cloud function? Or other way to get the Memory Usage and list Job ID? Also can you share the docs you are using?

Comment: @JaysonM, thanks for the help.  I'm not sure what you're asking but maybe this answers your question.  I'm using Google Cloud Monitoring and would like to add a custom metric to help solve this issue.  I have thousands of "jobs", each job will call the same GC Function but with specific user parameters.  Sometimes a job has an error or the memory exceeds what I would expect.  In that case, I would like to be able to identify which parameters were passed to GC Function so I can re-run the job and debug the issue.  Does that help? (I added this comment as an update to the question as well)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on setting up on the Cloud Function side but below are the steps to check the Job ID and the memory using Cloud Monitoring Metric Explorer.

JOB ID

1. Go to Monitoring
2. Mertric Explorer
3. On Resource & Metric Select **Cloud Scheduler Job** > **Log Based Metric** > **Log Bytes**
4. Apply
5. View Data **Group by** > **Job ID**

Memory

1. ID
2. Go to Monitoring
3. Mertric Explorer
4. On Resource & Metric Select **Cloud Function** > **Function** > **Memory Usage**
5. Apply

Cloud Monitoring will only help you view metrics, events and metadata. You can try to also use Cloud Logging Instead to alert you based on your metrics.

Found below docs that might help you with the logging. You can add this [Reporting Errors](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) to your Cloud Functions to list it on Cloud Logging.

To view the logs

1. Go to Logging
2. Logs Explorer
3. Query
4. **Resource** (Cloud Scheduler Job/Cloud Function) > Location > Job ID > Apply
5. Create Alert

Other Docs that might help you on Cloud Logging 
[Log-based metrics overview](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#user-metrics) 
[Cloud Functions Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/nodejs?hl=en#cloud_functions)

Comment: Does this answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I will highly recommend using Cloud Monitoring Metric Explorer and MQL for tracking monitoring data.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-editor?hl=en

You might find your desired metrics in [this list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp?hl=en) or prepare your custom metrics. The `job_id` should be a metric field (dimension). If so, you can write a MQL query like this:

```
fetch resource_of_your_metric 
# `gce_instance` for example
| metric your_metric 
# `compute.googleapis.com/guest/memory/bytes_used` for example
| group_by [metric.job_id], .sum
| filter val() > some_limit
```